# Java - object of a private inner class being as an argument to an outer class' constructor

Tags: java, constructor, private, inner-classes

```
public class Person
{
    private class Date
    {
        public Date(int month, int day, int year)
        {
            ...
        }
    }


    private String name;
    private Date birthDate;

    public Person(String name, Date birthDate)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Above, I have an outer class, Person, and a private inner class, Date. The constructor for a Person object should take Date as one of its arguments.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person testPerson = new Person("Mr. Sandman", new Date(1, 1, 1970));
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to create a Person object in my separate "testing" file, Test.java, (above) (which is located in the same folder as my Person.java file), I get an error.

The error is this: "error: no suitable constructor found for Person(String,Date)"
(The compiler references the line on which I instantiate testPerson as the cause of the error.)

The question: What am I doing wrong? Also, how can I create a Person object and pass a Date object into Person's constructor? (Is this even possible if Date is a private inner class of Person?)

Comment: Why must `Date` be an inner class of `Person`? That seems illogical. Move `Date` outside `Person` and it will solve all your problems.

Comment: Presumably as you can't instantiate a `Person.Date` object like that, that's actually a different `Date` class being used in your `Test` class...

Comment: @miorel It must be an inner class because that is what my homework assignment specified. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` is a private inner class of `Person`, so you are not going to be able to create an instance of it from another (non-Person) class. Two things:

- In order to make your current design work, change the access of `Date` from private to public
- You will also need to create a default constructor for the `Person` class, since you need an instance of it to create the inner class.
- Please consider changing your inner class name. There is already a `Date` class in the SDK.

To be honest, you should just create your `Date` as a standalone class, as others have suggested.

Comment: I concur. There's no clear benefit to Date being an inner class, nor does it make sense; I don't see anything about it that should be private to the Person class. And why not just use java.util.Date? You could use the JodaTime library for more convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new `Person` constructor that takes a `java.util.Date` as it's second parameter and create a `Person.Date` object from the `java.util.Date` object (probably via a `Calendar` object).

You may as well also make you existing constructor `private` as no-one is ever going to be able to use it.